# Sql global from rename

Tags: sql, select

I'm writing a stored procedure which has a lot of selects with inner joins.

The table name is "Product" and I want to rename it as "P" so I can always contact it as "P.Id" (or any other random column).

The downside is that the only way I know, is that I have to use "Select From Products P" everywhere and I want to know if there's no easier way to globalize this.

So perhaps it is possible somehow to make P refer to Products even without having the From Products P or even reference to products if I type "From P"

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Do you want `Product` renamed as P for just the current stored procedure, or if you refer to `Product` ever again? Why can't you just use `FROM (SELECT * FROM Product) AS P` and then join against that from then on? Or are you doing lots of subqueries that select from `Product`?

Comment: Just this one.  And I have no idea what RDBMS is. All I use sql for is to make procedures and tables

Comment: You don't know if it's SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify the RDBMS you are using, but in SQL Server the only way I can think that you can do this is by using dynamic sql to execute your query. Then you would create a sql string to execute. Using dynamic SQL, you could the table names to a parameter that you add to the query string.

The code would be similar to this:

```
declare @p varchar(50) = 'Products'
declare @query varchar(max)

set @query = 'select * from '+@p

execute(@query);
```

If you are going to use dynamic sql, then I advise reading:

[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)